# Remote PowerShell Script not working with c#

Tags: c#, powershell

My Powershell Script that invoke some commands to remote machine (on same domain) works very well.

```
Invoke-Command -script { get-host } -ComputerName 'AD' -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('admin', (ConvertTo-SecureString 'passwd' -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

but My C# Rest API program that uses above code is not working.

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
  ps.AddScript(ps_script_above);
  Collection<PSObject> psOutput = ps.Invoke();

  logger.Debug("Result Count is : " + psOutput.Count);
}
```

Result Count is always zero.
But when except 'invoke-command' phrase, it works well.

My Powershell version is 7.x and dotnet version is 5.

Anyone with experience creating C# programs using remote powershell commands,
plz help me.

Comment: Inspect `ps.Streams.Error` to see if/what  errors occurred.

Comment: `AddScript` expects a string representing a script like in your case `"get-host"`.  Are you providing a string or a scriptblock?

Comment: I think it's better to use [`BeginInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) and [`EndInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.endinvoke?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) if you are wanting to wait for a response. `Invoke()` is a synchronous call.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to apply all of your comments to my code.